# omit post back in making ( << 1 2 3 4 >> )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i wanna make some thing like this ( << 1 2 3 4 >> ) end of my view . i used HTML.BeginForm  and it worked .but i had post back.so  i changed HTML.BeginForm  to Ajax.BeginForm , now it dose not work.

for example when i click on link 2 i get this error in fire bug :

```
    "  NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/myAction/search? pagenumber=2"
```

view:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm( "search ","MyAction",new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = ""
            }))
            {
          int page = (int)ViewBag.page;
          int pages = (int)ViewBag.pages;

         <div class="pagination pagination-left">
        <ul>
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("«", "MyAction", new { numberpage = pages })</li>
            @{for (int i = pages; i >= 1; i--)
              {
                  if (i == page)
                  {
                <li class="active">@HtmlAjax.ActionLink(i.ToString(), " MyAction ",  new { numberpage = i })</li>
                  }
                  else
                  {
                <li>@Ajax.ActionLink(i.ToString(), " MyAction ", new { numberpage =  i  })</li>
                  }
              }
            }
            <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("»", " MyAction ", new { numberpage = 1 })</li>

        </ul>


    </div>
```

my controller :

```
    [HttpPOST]
   public ActionResult search(int? numberpage)
   {
       int skip = 0;
       ViewBag.page ;
      Temp= myobjectclass.GetAll().tolist();
       ViewBag.pages = (Temp.Count() / 5) + 1;

       var db = new ProjectContext();

       var obj = new projectClass.myobjectclass();
       if (numberpage!= null)
       {
           skip = 5 * (numberpage.Value - 1);
           ViewBag.page = numberpage.Value;

       }
       obj.StudentRequierments = Temp.Skip(skip).Take(5).ToList();
       ViewBag.pages = (Temp.Count() / 5) + 1;

       return View(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should try like :-
View :-

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("EndUserSearch", "Search", **FormMethod.Get**))
{ %>
   // entire html page here
   // 

<%}
```

Controller:-

```
[httpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string Keywords, string sortBy = "SPName", bool ascending = true, int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
```

{

}

Every time you click on page number link it will take you on Search action and you do not need to post you page on to the server

Comment: I think `@Html.BeginForm` posts the page back. Instead you should use `@Ajax.BeginForm `

Comment: No, Here i suggest you to use the code in the same manner i shared with you, as this woks well here at my end

Comment: @DK Chauhan i did your suggestion . but now, i have post back  too. i update my question . please tell me my mistake

Comment: you can go through it, I believe it will will help you, this link have the explanation and source code as well                                      http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010511-1.aspx#postadlink                                            http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/code/GridDemosMVC.zip

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of html.beginform

```
 @using(Ajax.BeginForm(
new AjaxOptions{
HttpMethod="get",
InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId=""
}))
```

Comment: i did it before . of course with "POST" Method . when i click on any link , dose not accour any thing .for example when i click on link "1", it says  : "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/Home/search?pagenumber =1"  in fire bog."GET" is too .